# How to Set DevExpress WPF GridControl Look And Feel?

Tags: wpf, themes, devexpress, gridcontrol

Can anybody help me with changing the look and feels for the DevExpress Grid Control.Right now I am getting a blue Grid Control , my best guess is that I need to change the default theme from DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.DeepBlue.v12.1 to something else.Can anybody help me with this.
 Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XAML:

```
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
    dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2007Black">
```

Comment: SeToY Can We customize the Theme some how or just disable the theme and then style the gridcontrol

Comment: @kiran Yes, you can. You can edit each and every DevExpress theme with the ThemeEditor like described here: http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Themes/theme-editor.xml or add theming to the GridControl: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E1134.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You should only set the [ThemeManager.ThemeName](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfCoreThemeManager_ThemeNametopic) property:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.Window1" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core" 
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" 
    dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2007Black"> 
    ...
</Window>
```

Related link: [DevExpress WPF Themes](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7407)

Comment: Thanks for providing the WPF theme link ,I was about to google for that :)

Comment: @kiran You should not google for anything when you working with DevExpress, because there are [DevExpress Search](http://search.devexpress.com/) and [DevExpress Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice , I did that but i wasn't able to find any result

Comment: @DmitryG, perhaps the previous guy downvoted because DevExpress' own solutions to their Grids are frequently unsuitable for enterprise apps.